# Apache Commons IO in .Net

Tags: .net, apache-commons

Is there a library like Apache Commons IO for .Net?

I am looking for the following functions:

- IOUtils.toByteArray(Stream);
- IOUtils.toString(Stream);
- FileUtils.write*();
- DirectoryWalker.

Answer (score 2):

functionality like that is A PART of .net. no need for a special library.

examples:
http://www.xefteri.com/articles/show.cfm?id=8
https://web.archive.org/web/20210518224206/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/072303-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There's not a direct port, AFAIK, but Apache Commons IO includes a whole bunch of stuff:

- Utility classes - with static methods to perform common tasks
- Filters - various implementations of file filters
- Comparators - various implementations of `java.util.Comparator` for files
- Streams - useful stream, reader and writer implementations

Are you after something specific?

**Update:** for e.g. the functionality of IOUtils.toByteArray(Stream) you can use the equivalent

```
Stream stream;
byte[] bytes;
using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(stream)) {
        bytes = br.ReadBytes(stream.Length);
}
```

and, of course, to get a string from the byte array, you simply need to decode it using the appropriate encoding:

```
String s = encoding.GetString(bytes)
```

where encoding is a `System.Text.Encoding` instance, for example `System.Text.UTF8Encoding`. I'm not sure of any libraries which provide the other functions you describe, but they're easy to write using `TextWriter.WriteLine`, `BinaryWriter.Write`, `Directory.GetDirectories` and `Directory.GetFiles` as in [this example](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303974).

Comment: Yeap, toByteArray(Stream), toString(Stream) from (IOUtils) and write* from FileUtils.